# Virtual subdomains that forwards to a port with nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain

is it possible to create a virtual subdomain with nginx that redirects to a certain port on the same (physical) server?

I have something like this in mind (in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:25565;
    }
```

}

Unfortunately, that doesnt work. Do I need to actually, statically create A records on the DNS to point to a certain port?